# Confused on notation for matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

I'm doing linear algebra homework, where's I'm supposed to find the spanning set for the following vector space:
$$\{A \in M_2(\mathbb{R}): A\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}  = A\begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\}$$

What exactly does this notation mean? I'm confused.

Comment: The set of matrices which satisfy the given equation.

Comment: Would be a good question to ask the person who assigns the homework.

Comment: In other words, the set of 2 by 2 matrices $A$ such that $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\end{pmatrix}$ lies in $\ker A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were to read the notation symbol-by-symbol, I would come up with this:

> The set of all $2 \times 2$ matrices $A$ with real entries such that
>   $$
> A \pmatrix{1\\2} = A \pmatrix{0\\0}
> $$

So, for example, 
$
\left( \begin{smallmatrix}-2&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)
$
is an element of this set, but 
$
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0\\0&1
\end{smallmatrix} \right)
$
is not.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify my question what exactly does A(1; 2) mean? Like does it refer to the 1st and 2nd element of matrix A?

Comment: It is called matrix vector product.

Comment: Oh I feel really stupid I didn't get that lol